# How to identify if a package is a child of another package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've developed an ETL framework in SSIS, based on the parent/child pattern.

Child packages do the heavy lifting, while the parent package controls execution and logging.

One of my design goals is to allow child packages to run independently of the parent package, for the purpose of testing and development.  To enable this it helps if the package knows when it is a child, and when it is running in its own process.

I was planning to add a boolean variable, called something like session::debugMode.  The value would be based on an expression.  But I cannot find the right combination of system variables to detect when there is/is not a parent package.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you passing any variables from the parent package to the child? If so, cant you default that to a certain value and query that during debug mode? Additionally, there are no known system variables that will tell you whether a package is mater or child.

Comment: Thanks @rvphx. That's what I suspected. I ended up following the model you describe. I was hoping to use an evaluated var, as they are effectively read-only. Longer term I suspect I'll switch to a project deployment model, which might change my approach.